# Create readmore link for custom module

Tags: joomla-3.x, module

I've created a very simple slideshow module. I have a **helper.php** that gives me all articles of a given category. My problem is that i don't know how to create the *readmore link*.

That's what i have:

```
public static function getSildes() {
    // return var having the complete carousel stuff
    $slide = ""; 
    // a counter for bootstrap active flag
    $counter = 0;

    // my database connection
    $db = JFactory::getDbo();

    // i need the cat_id of category named "Bootyslide"
    $module = JModuleHelper::getModule('mod_bootyslide');
    $category = new JRegistry($module->params);
    $cat_id = (int) $category['mycategory'];

    // and now i select all the articles with the category id
    $query = $db->getQuery(true);
    $query->select('*');
    $query->from('#__content');
    $query->where('catid="' . $cat_id . '"');
    $query->where('state="1"');
    $db->setQuery((string)$query);
    $results = $db->loadObjectList();


    foreach($results as $result){
        $images  = json_decode($result->images);
        $image = $images->image_fulltext;
        $text = $result->introtext;
        $alias = $result->alias;
        $fulltext = $result->fulltext;
        ($counter == 0) ? $active = "active" : $active = "";
        $slide .= " <div class=\"item " . $active . "\">";

        if (strlen($image) > 0) {
            $slide .= "     <img src=\"" . $image . "\">";
        }
        $slide .= " <div class=\"carousel-caption\">
                        <div class=\"container\">
                            <div>
                                " . $text . "
                            </div>
                            <!-- the readmore link -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div> ";
        ++$counter;
    }

    return $slide;

}
```

I know that when the column fulltext has values, I should create the readmore link, that's not the problem. I really don't know how to create the URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>Try the following</strike>

```
<a href="<?php echo $result->link; ?>">Read more</a>
```

For some reason assumed you were using the content model...my bad.

Try this:

```
<?php
    $link = JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=' . $result->id);
    echo '<a href="' . $link . '">Read more</a>
?>
```

But just on a side note, I would suggest you put all your HTML in the **default.php** as this file is supposed to be used for all your markup, allowing users to create Template Overrides.

Comment: +1 on default.php, especially on a slideshow, where people reasonably might want to adjust output to match the site. (Since they are used as graphical elements.)

Comment: $result->link is empty, I get the notice: `Undefined property: stdClass::$link in ...`

Comment: @DaFunkyAlex - I've updated my answer